# Trying to solve a simple-looking recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I have this recurrence relation that I've been trying to solve,

$$g_m = g_{m-1} + a_m \, g_{m-2}$$

with $g_1=g_0=1$ and $m\geq 0$. Here, $a_m$ is the $m$-th term of a known sequence. Any ideas?

If it helps, $a_m= \frac{1}{L^2}(m-1)(r-m+2)$ where $L^2 \in \mathbb{Z}, L^2 \neq0 $, $r \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $r \geq |L|$, but other than that, $L$ and $r$ are free. So, if I were to be extremely precise, $g_m$ and $a_m$ would actually be $g_{mrL}$ and $a_{mrL}$.

*Brute-forcing the problem reveals a pattern, but I don't see how to write it in closed form. Perhaps someone with greater pattern-recognition skills than mine could see a closed form:*

- $g_2 = 1 + a_2$
- $g_3 = 1 + a_2 + a_3$
- $g_4= 1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_2 a_4$
- $g_5= 1 + a_2+ a_3+a_4+a_5+a_2a_4+a_2a_5+a_3a_5$
- $g_6=  1 + a_2+ a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_2a_4+a_2a_5+a_2a_6+a_3 a_5 + a_3 a_6 + a_4 a_6 + a_2 a_4 a_6 $
- $g_7=  1 + a_2+ a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+ a_7 + a_2 a_4 + a_2 a_5 + a_2 a_6 + a_2 a_7 + a_3 a_5 + a_3 a_6 +a_3 a_7 + a_4 a_6 + a_4 a_7 + a_5 a_7 + a_2 a_4 a_6 + a_2 a_4 a_7 + a_2 a_5 a_7 + a_3 a_5 a_7$
- $g_8 = 1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 +a_6 + a_7 + a_8 + a_2 a_4 + a_2 a_5 + a_2 a_6 + a_2 a_7 + a_2 a_8 +a_3 a_5 + a_3 a_6 + a_3 a_7 + a_3 a_8 + a_4 a_6 + a_4 a_7 +a_4 a_8 + a_5 a_7 + a_5 a_8 + a_6 a_8 + a_2 a_4 a_6 + a_2 a_4 a_7+a_2 a_4 a_8 + a_2 a_5 a_7 + a_2 a_5 a_8 + a_2 a_6 a_8 + a_3 a_5 a_7 + a_3 a_5 a_8 + a_3 a_6 a_8 + a_4 a_6 a_8 + a_2 a_4 a_6 a_8$

Comment: If $f_n := g_n/g_{n-1},$ then $f_n = 1 + a_n/f_{n-1}$ which expresses $f_n$ as a continued fraction. There may be continued fraction results that you can use in your case. In particular, the Wikipedia article [Continuant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant_(mathematics)) may help you.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: @Somos Yeah, this seems to help, but only in cases where all $g_n$ are non-zero. Counter-example would be $L=2i$ and $r=4$. In general, only $r$ odd satisfies the non-zero condition, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You can often rewrite these problems like:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
g_m\\g_{m-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&a_m\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g_{m-1}\\g_{m-2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

In vector and matrix notation, this becomes:
$$G_m = A_m G_{m-1}$$

For example, $a_m=1$ would provide the Fibonacci numbers, for $g_0=g_1=1$.

If $A_m$ doesn't depend on $m$ then you can diagonalize it and get an explicit answer (by multiplying it $n$ times):
$$G_m = PD^nP^{-1} G_0$$

If $a_m$ is more general then it's not obvious if this works.

Comment: Are you sure this works if $a_m$ depends on $m$? Isn't the method you described simply a linear-algebraic way of solving a linear recurrence relation with *constant* coefficients? By the way, $a_m$ is a quadratic polynomial in $m$.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work, as long as you have a different matrix for each new term. Then you can't diagonalize it obviously. I'll amend the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: You should add in your question that $a_m$ is a quadratic polynomial, it's quite relevant. @lel

Comment: There, I updated the question, thanks for the suggestion.